# css() is not setting background property for body tag

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, css

I have used these things in my code, but none of them worked..Kindly Suggest me any other way for resolving this issue.

```
// #1
if ("${actionBean.backgroundImage}" != null){
    $(document.body).css("pointer-events", "none");
    $(document.body).css("cursor", "default");
    $(document.body).css("background", "url('${actionBean.backgroundImage}') no-repeat fixed center -80px / cover !important");
} 

// #2
if ("${actionBean.backgroundImage}" != null){
    $('html, body').css("pointer-events", "none");
    $('html, body').css("cursor", "default");
    $('html, body').css("background", "url('${actionBean.backgroundImage}') no-repeat fixed center -80px / cover !important");
}

// #3
if ("${actionBean.backgroundImage}" != null){
    $("body").css("pointer-events","none");
    $("body").css("cursor","default");
    $("body").css("background", "url('${actionBean.backgroundImage}') no-repeat fixed center -80px / cover !important");
}

// #4
if ("${actionBean.backgroundImage}" != null){
    $(body).css("pointer-events", "none");
    $(body).css("cursor", "default");
    $(body).css("background", "url('${actionBean.backgroundImage}') no-repeat fixed center -80px / cover !important");
}
```

Comment: what does this mean `${actionBean.backgroundImage}`.is this a `selector`

Comment: Your logic is flawed; `"${actionBean.backgroundImage}" != null` will *never* be `false`, even if the value is `''`.

Comment: ${actionBean.backgroundImage} ...
It is a Stripes variable....and condition is not false here...
I am using Stripes Framework...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the separate properties for background such as:

```
$(body).css("background", "no-repeat fixed center -80px / cover !important");

$(body).css("background-image", "url('${actionBean.backgroundImage}')");
```

and this must be included below the body.

Comment: Yes its working...But please explain me..how it is doing things correctly ?
Do I have a problem with the logic in code ?

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this by giving id to your body class ....and use it for adding CSS

```
if ("${actionBean.backgroundImage}" != null){
  $("#bodyId").css("pointer-events", "none");
  $("#bodyId").css("cursor", "default");
  $("#bodyId").css("background", "url('${actionBean.backgroundImage}') no-repeat fixed center -80px / cover !important");
```

}